# Python - Accessing Multiple Values in list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am sorry for not sharing detailed information, see below code
*

```
import json
import requests
def funcname(): 
    response = requests.get('https:aig.com/e/id')
    parsed_response = json.loads(response.text)
    print(parsed_response)
    print(type(parsed_response))
```

If I run the above the code, I get the following output:

```
{'values': [{'id': '123456','name': 'person1'}, {'id': '-1123678','name': 'person2'},{'id': '566','name': 'person3'}, {'id': '-1123678','name': 'person4'},{'id': '-1123678','name': 'person5'}]}
<class 'dict'>
```

There are actually 100+ entries, I just listed these 5

I would like to create a python program to ask for input for person name and print the id based on name we give.

So, suppose if I prompted the user for a `name` of a person and user input `person3`, the output should be the id `566`

Unfortunately, the provided code is throwing an error.

Comment: I'm curious to know if you need to use a list, or if it would suffice to simply use a dictionary and avoid the unnecessary extra parsing that using a list would require. My intuition tells me that just using a single dictionary with key/value pairs is the way this should be done.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Do you have to do a lot of look ups or just a few? If a lot one should probably build indexing dicts. Otherwise just do a linear search.

Answer (score 3):

You can construct a dictionary and index into it based on your input:

```
>>> myList = [{'id': '123','name': 'one'},{'id': '-1123','name': 'two'},{'id': '566','name': 'three'}]
>>> nameToId = dict((e['name'], e['id']) for e in myList)
>>> nameToId[input("Enter a name: ")]
Enter a name: two
'-1123'
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try it:

```
myDict = {'values': [{'id': '123456','name': 'person1'}, {'id': '-1123678','name': 'person2'},{'id': '566','name': 'person3'}, {'id': '-1123678','name': 'person4'},{'id': '-1123678','name': 'person5'}]};


for i in range(len(myDict['values'])):
    if(myDict['values'][i]['name'] == 'person3'):
        print(myDict['values'][i]['id'])
```

or

```
myDict = {'values': [{'id': '123456','name': 'person1'}, {'id': '-1123678','name': 'person2'},{'id': '566','name': 'person3'}, {'id': '-1123678','name': 'person4'},{'id': '-1123678','name': 'person5'}]};
        
        
name = input("Enter name: \n")

for i in range(len(myDict['values'])):
    if(myDict['values'][i]['name'] == name):
        print(myDict['values'][i]['id'])
```

Answer (score 2):

So you have your list

```
mylist = [{'id': '123','name': 'one'},{'id': '-1123','name': 'two'},{'id': '566','name': 'three'}]
```

Now, let's say you have defined a variable

```
myname = "one"
```

All you have to do is search for the corresponding `id` with that name:

```
[item["id"] for item in mylist if item["name"] == myname]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [{'id': '123','name': 'one'},{'id': '-1123','name': 'two'},{'id': '566','name': 'three'}]
name = input()
for i in a:
    if i['name'] == name:
        print(i['id'])
        break
```